# python argument inside function

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to pass argument inside function but no successes.
the purpose of this function is to return xml tag 
this code doesn't work:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def xmlTag(message):
 conf = open('timeLimit.conf').read().lower()
 for config in conf.splitlines():
    if config in conf.splitlines():
        data = BeautifulSoup(conf, "lxml")
        tag = data.message
        print(tag['msg'])

    break
```

xmlTag("fun2")

if i put fun2 instead of "message" variable, like this "tag = data.fun2" the code works
please help
what i"m doing wrong

Comment: Method names can't be parameters in Python. Consider passing a lambda as the parameter that accepts data as its input and returns a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try doing:

... 
   tag = getattr(data, message)
   ...

getattr is the way of retrieving an attribute from an object when you have its name in a variable.

(Though your code have some other issues as well - that `break` statement where it is ensures your loop will terminate on the first iteration, for example)